# Loss function returns x whereas tensorflow shows validation loss as (x+0.0567)

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have a custom loss function. In order to experiement how the loss is calculated during valiation, I update the loss function as follows:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0 * tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=-tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=y_true_1 * tf.math.log(y_pred_1), axis=-1)) + 1
```

- Multiply by 0, to make the data dependent loss value as always 0.
- Add a constant value like 1 to it, so that the loss function always returns a value of 1.

Now when I run `model.evaluate` on my data, tensorflow shows me the loss value as `1.0567`.

To further experiment, I updated the constant value being returned by loss function from `1` to other constant values. Below you can see the table:

- constant 0 => loss 0.0567
- constant 1 => loss 1.0567
- constant 2 => loss 2.0567

I was expecting the final calculated loss to be same as the constant value I passed. But that's not the case. What is the reason for a constant difference of 0.0567?

I have verified it across three versions of tensorflow: 1.14.0, 1.15.0, and 2.1.0.

Comment: I'm not used to tf but looking at how the official loss functions are implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py), they seem to convert constants using `ops.convert_to_tensor(0.5, dtype=...),` and then multiply them using `math_ops.multiply`. That might affect the backpropagation graph. (specifically I was looking at the `huber_loss` implementation)

Comment: Thanks @AKareem for your inputs. I think that doesn't apply to my situation though.. In my case, I'm using a custom loss function, which should bypass all of those layers. And those parameters like 0.5 is applicable only for some specific loss functions.

Comment: Oh sure I understand your point, I meant just for experimental purposes try using `ops.convert_to_tensor(0, dtype=...)` and `math_ops.multiply`.

Comment: On further investigation, figured it out. 
One of my FC layers had a l2 regulariation as follows:
`model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1))`. Naturally when we add an L2 regularization like this, a correspnoding term will automatically get added to the loss function, which is what that 0.567 seems to be reflecting!

Comment: If I comment out the l2 regularization from the model, the loss value goes down to zero, as expected...

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation was able to narrow it down.

The loss value is not only calculated by the response from loss function, but also the various `regularizers` added in the intermediate layers.

And one of the FC layers in my model was indeed having a L2 regularization term as below:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1))
```

If I remove the l2 regularization, the loss goes indeed goes to zero if the loss function returns a zero.